# MongoDB - Combine filter with default filter

Tags: mongodb

I'm hoping to do a very common task which is to never delete items that I store, but instead just mark them with a deleted flag. However, for almost every request I will now have to specify `deleted:false`. Is there a way to have a "default" filter on which you can add? Such that I can construct a `live_items` filter and do queries on top of that?

This was just one guess at a potential answer. In general, I'd just like to have `deleted=False` be the default search.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and just made a python function that combines the specified query:

```
def find_items(filt, single=False, live=True):
  if live:
    live = {'deleted': False}
    filt = dict(filt.items() + live.items())
  if single:
    return db.Item.find_one(filt)
  else:
    return db.Item.find(filt)
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you would do this with a view, but unfortunately MongoDB doesn't support views.

But when queries which exclude items which are marked as deleted are far more frequent than those which include them, you could remove the deleted items from the main `items` collection and put them in a separate `items_deleted` collection. This also has the nice side-effect that the performance of the collection of active items doesn't get impaired by a large number of deleted items. The downside is that indices can't be guaranteed to be unique over both collections.